# Проверить, существует ли пользователь, если нет - создать. Ansible

Tags: ansible

Нужно проверить существует ли пользователь. 
Если пользователь не существует - создать его. 
Если  существует - остановить сценарий.

Думал что через `stat` будет работать - но вывело ошибку. 
Пример код:

```
- name: Check that the user exists
  stat: 
    name: "{{ username }}"
  register: stat_result

- name: Create user, if it doesnt exist already
  user:
    name: "{{ username }}"
    state: present
  when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: Ну stat явно не предназначен для работы с пользователями

Comment: Это я привел пример, чтобы Вы смогли понять суть моей проблемы :)

Comment: Ну и непонятно, чем вам собственно `user: name="{{ username }}" state=present` не угодил. Если пользователя нет, то он его создаст, если есть, то ничего не делает, дальнейшие задачи можно отменить через те же register и when — ровно то, что вы хотите

Comment: модуль user для того и оформлен модулем, что сам проверяет текущее состояние и приводит к запрошенному при необходимости. state=present достаточно

Comment: Суть в том, что имя пользователя и название домашнего каталога - это одна переменная. И, если я запущу сценарий без проверки, и укажу пользователя, который существует - сценарий перезапишет домашний каталог пользователя, что мне как раз и не надо. Вот по этому мне и нужна проверка пользователя, что бы сценарий останавливался, если пользователь существует.

Comment: Уберите when вообще. Модуль user сам прекрасно понимает, когда пользователь есть, а когда нет. А home прекрасно устанавливается через этот же модуль. Или вы хотите не ansible way: когда конфигурация не описывается ansible'ом и не должа им модифицироваться. Настройки каждого home должны описываться правилом, зашитым в плейбуки и/или конфиги.

Comment: @rorry47 почему вы считаете, что сценарий перепишет каталог? Он не должен выполняться, если пользователь уже есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос следующим способом:

```
 - name: Check user
   getent:
     database: passwd
     key: "{{ username }}"
   register: user_result
   ignore_errors: yes

 - name: Check user2  
   shell: echo 1
   failed_when: user_result|success

 - debug:
     var: getenta

 - debug:
     var: user
```

Если существует - выдаст ошибку и остановит сценарий.
Если не существует - выдаст ошибку, проигнорирует и будет выполнять сценарий дальше.

Answer (score 3):

Вам вполне хватит возможностей [модуля user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_module.html):

```
- name: Create user, if it doesnt exist already
  user:
    name: "{{ user.name }}"
    home: "{{ user.home }}"
    state: present
```

Comment: Я повторюсь: имя пользователя и название домашнего каталога - это одна переменная. И, если я запущу сценарий без проверки, и укажу пользователя, который существует - сценарий перезапишет домашний каталог пользователя, что мне как раз и не надо. Вот по этому мне и нужна такая проверка пользователя, что бы сценарий останавливался, если пользователь, которого я указал при запуске, существует.

Comment: @rorry47 как я уже говорил в своём комментарии — непонятно, чем вам не угодили register и when для остановки сценария в сочетании с модулем user

Comment: @rorry47 модуль user не создаёт пользователя, если его уже нет. В любом случае, попробуйте на тестовой тачке выполнить этот код.

Comment: @nick-volynkin Я это знаю, но этот код не решает мою проблему.

Comment: @rorry47 окей, мне печально, что вы не хотите воспользоваться более хорошими практиками, но давайте попробуем решить именно вашу проблему. Я вижу следующий вариант: регистрация переменных работает в случае если можно сделать листинг файла/каталога, можно проверять наличие папки в /home/ или где у вас перенесён /home. Подскажите, это будет считаться достаточным для вас условием, что существует данный пользователь или у вас более сложная система?

Comment: @a-k Не совсем понимаю зачем листинг, если вся суть в том - чтобы остановить сценарий если пользователь уже есть. Ладно. В течении нескольких часов на поиск ответа я пришёл к тому, что просто устраиваю проверку пользователя через `getent: database=passwd key={{ username }} fail_key=False` и уже через `failed_when` хочу зафэйлить если `kay` найден. Если нет - выполнять плейбук дальше.

Comment: @rorry47 Потому что stat...register не работает с проверкой пользователей. Вот я и предложил вариант: проверяйте наличие каталога на диске, а вы пришли к варианту "проверять в БД". Подошло бы любое действие, которое с одной стороны работает с регистрацией переменных, а с другой - устраивает вас в качестве надёжного и точного определения существует/не существует.